# xquery efficient predicates versus for...where

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a series of xml nodes that look like this:

```
let $x := 
 <works>
   <work xml:id="W1">
      <author corresp="AU08"/>
      <group corresp="GR03"/>
   </work>
   <work xml:id="W2">
      <author corresp="AU09"/>
      <group corresp="GR10"/>
   </work>
   <work xml:id="W3">
      <author corresp="AU08"/>
      <group corresp="GR05"/>
   </work>
    ....
 </works>
```

I have a search form that may or may not offer sequence parameters against `work/@xml:id` , `work/author/@corresp`, and `work/affiliation/$corresp`, for example:

```
let $xmlids := ("W1")
let $authors := ()
let $groups := ("GR05","GR08")
```

or

```
let $xmlids := ()
let $authors := ("AU01","AU08")
let $groups := ("GR05")
```

I am trying to create an efficient query in Xquery 3.1 (eXist 4.7) to account for the different permutations of parameters, while outputting `work/`. This has lead me to build an ugly series of nested `if` statements which trying to favour predicates over `for ...where` like the following:

```
if (count($xmlids) gt 0 and count($authors) gt 0 and count($groups) gt 0)
   then 
      $x/id($xmlids)/author[@corresp=$authors]/parent::work/group[@corresp=$groups]/parent::work
else if (count($xmlids) gt 0 and count($authors) gt 0 and count($groups) eq 0)
   then 
      $x/id($xmlids)/author[@corresp=$authors]/parent::work
else if ...
```

Is there a more efficient way to build an Xquery accounting for variable present/absent parameters?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to return anything if the variable `$xmlids` is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: empty would be the same as `count($xmlids) = 0`....wouldn't it? Anyway, any of the count of sequences could equal 0.

Comment: If the parameter is the empty sequence, do you want to return no `work` elements in that case or then all of them, ignoring the parameter? If you use `$x/id($xmlids)` with the empty sequence it will return no nodes.

Comment: Right that's part of my problem: how to account for empty sequences. Empty sequences should return all results. This is why I've resorted to a series of  `if...else if` statements..8 or 9 for the different combinations of 3 parameters...

Comment: Your target isn't really clear. For example, in your first group of `let`s, work "W1" has group 3, not 5 or 8 (actually no work has group 8). So, from the 3 items in `let`s - do they have to belong to the same work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the predicates you just want `@corresp=$authors or not(exists($authors))` and `@corresp=$groups or not(exists($groups))`.

For the `id` call I think you need

```
let $work-items := if ($x/id($xmlids)) then $x/id($xmlids) else $x/work
return $work-items[author[@corresp=$authors or not(exists($authors))] and group[@corresp=$groups or not(exists($groups))]]
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever used an element inside a predicate like `[author[@corresp=$authors or not(exists($authors))]` I didn't know that was possible. In this context is `[author[@corresp=$authors...` always equivalent to `[./author[@corresp=$authors...` ?

Comment: @jbrehr, yes, inside any predicate the expression is evaluated with each item of the left hand side (e.g. each `work` element in `$work-items`) as the context node and of course `author` in a relative expression like a predicate is equivalent to `child::author` or `./author` if you prefer.